# WooCommerce REST API - Get Custom Fields for Order

Tags: wordpress, rest, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm using the WooCommerce REST API (http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#introduction) and are able to download Customers, Orders etc successfully.

My customer has added some custom fields to the checkout page, e.g.:

```
po_number
accounts_email
```

I would like to be able to GET these custom fields when requesting an ORDER, e.g.:

```
/wp-json/wc/v1/orders/4568
```

At the moment none of the custom fields are returned when I GET an Order. I've tried adding

```
?filter[meta]=true
```

to the request URL but that doesn't make any difference. Is there a way I can modify the GET URL to include all custom fields? Couldn't find any reference in the REST API docs to custom fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have struggled like you did, but then it turns out using the newer v2 REST API solves the issue for me. So instead of:

```
/wp-json/wc/v1/orders/4568
```

I now use:

```
/wp-json/wc/v2/orders/4568
```

And custom fields will be included in the response with the key `meta_data`, even with those hidden fields starting with `_`.