# Woocommerce getting rest response from custom checkout fields

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am new to wordpress, Woocommerce and Rest api. Although lots of lots of searching I came down to  [this](https://www.kathyisawesome.com/woocommerce-customize-checkout-fields/) tutorial for how to add custom  checkout fields for my website.

Now it works fine in my website.

My questions is...

Where does these fields added in database? How do I get/edit those fields through json response(i.e. Woocommerce/wordpress rest Api). I am using woocommerce Rest api now to get customer details. it shows me only these details how do i get newly added fields?

```
[customer] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 59
            [created_at] => 2017-05-25T23:43:21Z
            [email] => arw@rediffmail.com
            [first_name] => xxxxxxxxx
            [last_name] => xxxxxxxxxx
            [username] => arw8055
            [role] => customer
            [last_order_id] => 2924
            [last_order_date] => 2017-05-29T11:32:50Z
            [orders_count] => 13
            [total_spent] => 2857.00
            [avatar_url] => http://2.gravatar.com/avatar/e1fb1c835c99bc9bf580dd3d432e4ad1?s=96
            [billing_address] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [first_name] => xxxxxxxxx
                    [last_name] => xxxxxxxxxx
                    [company] => 
                    [address_1] => er
                    [address_2] => rrrr
                    [city] => 
                    [state] => 
                    [postcode] => 
                    [country] => 
                    [email] => 
                    [phone] => 
                )

            [shipping_address] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [first_name] => 
                    [last_name] => 
                    [company] => 
                    [address_1] => 
                    [address_2] => 
                    [city] => 
                    [state] => 
                    [postcode] => 
                    [country] => 
                )

        )
```

Comment: which version of Rest API you are using?

Comment: Woocommerce Rest Api V3

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42100572/woocommerce-rest-api-get-custom-fields-for-order) can help, it say by default all the `meta_field` are included in `v2`, you can give it a try.

Comment: one more point even in Admin end also you won't see and data against the custom field in user panel, because data provided during checkout are stored in `postmeta` table with `post_ID` set to `order_id` and data provided in my account page are stored in `usermeta` table against `user_id`.

Comment: Thankyou renuka for your response. So what you saying is not possible to get `postmeta` by `user_id/customer_id`? And i have tried using `wp-json/wc/v1/orders/2924` this it wont show custom fields

Comment: yes, but `v1` does not support that, you have to either use `v2` or `v3`. like `/wp-json/wc/v2/orders/<order_id>` or `/wp-json/wc/v3/orders/<order_id>`

Comment: Any other options? as you suggesting  `wp-json api- v2/v3`  and it does not show custom fields fields . and thank you for your help